# Nuget manager not visible

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am getting following error once i run the project in visual studio 2012.

> Warning   1   Some NuGet packages were installed using a target framework
>   different from the current target framework and may need to be
>   reinstalled. Visit
>   http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/reinstalling-packages for more
>   information.  Packages affected: Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure,
>   SignalR.Hosting.AspNet, SignalR.Server

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling packages seem pretty straightforward. But, it can get very tricky since the following may affect or be affected by it:

Project retargeting or project upgrade where the target framework of the project gets changed Package dependencies and their versionsDependent packages and their versions.
I suggest you should read this document.

https://docs.nuget.org/consume/reinstalling-packages

read **When to Reinstall Packages and What to Watch for** section.

Comment: the problem is I can not see the nuget package manager console at all. 
I can not uninstall the nuget package manager neither can install it. 
This nuget thing is big issue in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: can you provide me a screenshot of your visual studio window ?

Comment: I can not add Image, it is saying:

"We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more."

What specifically you want to see ??\

Comment: did u try remove vs 2012 and install vs 2015 ??

Comment: I faced this issue before, I think you should delete your current version, and try reinstall a new one. you should try it in another PC, if it works, the problem is in your machine and your version of visual studio, if not, so we can fix you project structure.